# Filtering an array with an array of values

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have 2 arrays and i'd like to filter one array with the other. E.g. if array1 includes any of the values in array2, they should be returned.

The two arrays are:

```
const array1 = [a, b, c, d]
```

The other array, which should be filtered where 'id' is equal to any of the values in array1 is:

```
const array2 = [
{
   id: b
   title: title1
},
{
   id: d
   title: title2
},
{
   id: f
   title: title3
}
]
```

Comment: And what did you try so far?

Comment: Sidenotes: you forgot `"`

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use two for-loops. Possible not the fastest approach.

```
res = [];
for (var i = 0;i<array1.length;i++) {
    for (var j = 0;j<array2.length;j++) {
        if (array1[i] == array2[j].id) {
            res.push(array2[j]);
             break;
        }
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [Array.prototype.indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf):

```
const array1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];

const array2 = [{
   id: 'b',
   title: 'title1'
}, {
   id: 'd',
   title: 'title2'
}, {
   id: 'f',
   title: 'title3'
}];

const result = array2.filter(function(x){
    return array1.indexOf(x.id) !== -1;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding this missing `''`, You can use `filter` and `includes` methods of Array.

```
const array1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
const array2 = [
    {
       id: 'b',
       title: 'title1'
    },
    {
       id: 'd',
       title: 'title2'
    },
    {
       id: 'f',
       title: 'title3'
    }
]

const result = array2.filter(({id}) => array1.includes(id));
console.log(result);
```